# Странное поведение цикла

Tags: циклы

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему если я закоменчу строку `printf("%lf %lf\n", u1, u2);`, то цикл заканчивается при условии указанном в if, а если эта строка не закоменчена, то цикл продолжается бесконечно:

```
double originalF1(double);
double originalF2(double);
double f1(double, double, double);
double f2(double, double, double);

int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 3;
    double u1 = 2, u2 = exp(1.0), h = (double)(b-a)/10, x = a;

    do
    {
        u1 = u1 + h*f1(x, u1, u2);
        u2 = u2 + h*f2(x, u1, u2);

        printf("%lf %lf\n", u1, u2);

        if (x >= b && fabs(u1 - originalF1(x)) <= 0.0001 && fabs(u2 - originalF2(x)) <= 0.0001) 
            break;
        else if (x >= b)
        {
            x = a;
            h /= 2;
            u1 = 2;
            u2 = exp(1.0);
        }
        x += h;
    } while (true);

    return 0;
   }

double originalF1(double x)
{
    return 2 * x;
}

double originalF2(double x)
{
    return exp(x);
}

double f1(double x, double u1, double u2)
{
    return u1 / x - u2 / exp(x) + 1;
}

double f2(double x, double u1, double u2)
{
    return u1 / (2 * x) + u2 - 1;
}
```

Comment: а компилятор не ругается случаем на `%lf %lf` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, извините, я тут недавно, вопрос личный - почему Вы не оформили это сообщение как ответ (первая версия Вашей реплики)? просто хочу понять, как самому поступать в таком случае

Comment: @ale потому, что это не ответ, а уточнение по вопросу. Если что-то хотите уточнить у автора вопроса, надо писать в комментарии, если знаете ответ на вопрос - ответом, что логично........а что за первую версию?

Comment: компилятор не ругается на %lf %lf

Comment: да, это понятно,просто сначала Вы написали - именно законченный ответ - про бесконечный цикл в любом случае. Но понятно, сами Вы пока это ответом не посчитали, спасибо

Comment: @ale с тем первым я просто поспешил....вот и удалил.....

Comment: @JohnVein Сдается мне у вас переполнение памяти. и нехилое...а при ошибках ничего вы не делаете и всё виснет

Comment: вставлю свое предположение, может быть глупость, но вдруг...
инструкция printf("%lf %lf\n", u1, u2); - возможно неявно изменяет u1 и u2 (например округление), а при вычислении exp() больших аргументов - это может изменить результат (глюки на границе переполнения) и соответственно нарушить сходимость вычисляемого выражения (не происходит снижение погрешности при переходе к следующей иттерации)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что printf требует очень много ресурсов относительно остального кода. У вас больше миллиона итераций. Соответственно код выполняется во много раз дольше.

Как вариант можно вставить какое-либо условие перед printf, чтобы печатались только определенные итерации.

```
int counter = 0;
do
{
    u1 = u1 + h*f1(x, u1, u2);
    u2 = u2 + h*f2(x, u1, u2);
    counter++;
    if (counter%100000 == 0)printf("%lf %lf %i\n", u1, u2, counter);
```